# Why Tkinter geometry takes a string?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

I've recently been working on a project having to develop a simple GUI app using Python.  I was looking at setting the form size to a default value and came across the minsize and geometry methods.

minsize takes two arguments representing height and width.

geometry takes a single string representing the information.

I was wondering why the discrepancy?  Is there a good reason why a single string is a better argument than 2 (or 4 if you include position) values representing the size?

Thanks!

EDIT: so tkinter wraps the tcl functions.  Why the discrepancy in tcl?
Thanks all

Comment: Because `tkinter` Python library essentially just took all of the GUI tools from another language called `Tcl`. That's how `Tcl` takes the argument, so Python just follows suit. This is really a [tag:Tcl] question.

Comment: That explains tkinter... but simply shifts the question to tcl.. will update the tags

Comment: It's because Tcl reads its source code differently. Every kind of data can be expressed as a string, and there is no difference between numbers and strings or lists and strings. If the argument list is just two integers, it's easy to translate it to Pythonesque syntax. The geometry argument list is a lot harder to translate.

Comment: Tkinter is just a shallow wrapper around an embedded Tcl/Tk included in the Python stabdard library. The non-Pythonic parts of Tkinter are just passing strings through to the internal Tcl interpreter. The Pythonic parts are building up command strings and sending them along in the same way. You can even create Tcl instances within Python without invoking Tk at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, will have to check out Tcl at some point! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's historical. Tkinter is based on tcl/tk. Tcl/tk has it's roots in *nix systems (unix, linux, etc). The geometry format has been used for decades in the X11 windowing system, and tk was just a wrapper around the X11 libraries.

You can see the description of the X11 geometry specification in the X(7) man page. For example: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/X.7.html#sect6